# Как найти в базе запрос, один ко многим по нескольким условиям?

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

Как найти в базе запрос, один ко многим по нескольким условиям?

```
otd.findOne({where:{name: ot.name}})
              .then(otdsu=>{
                if(!otdsu) return;
                otdsu.getSubOtds()
                .then(subOtds=>{
                  for(sub of subOtds){
                    console.log(sub.name);
                  }
                })
                .catch();
              })
              .catch();
```

В этой части делается запрос к базе, в ot.name Административные службы. У Административных служб otdid = 2, т.е сейчас из общей базы выводятся все результаты с этим id, мне нужно что бы запрос искал еще совпадению по столбику pnd. Если просто добавить через запятую в запрос - работать не будет, т.к я понимаю он не просто в связывающей базе ищет. Как быть?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]